# How I can establish a saved cookie in Ion library when the app is destroyed?

Tags: android, cookies, android-ion

I have a cookie from the server and I save this cookie in a Shared Preference. When I send requests to the server from Ion library it goes right because I'm logged in the app and Ion has this cookie. And when I close the app and re-open, Ion has my cookie. The problem is when I destroyed the app, Ion doesn't have this cookie any more. And when I request a query to the server, it gives me a new one cookie and Ion has this new cookie. So, I need to establish the old cookie to the Ion library.

I've tried to set the cookie in the header:

```
String cookieString = ApiConstants.API_COOKIE_NAME + "=" + cookie;
headers.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Cookie", cookieString));

if (headers != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
        b = b.addHeader(headers.get(i).getName(), headers.get(i).getValue());
    }
}
```

And I've tried to add this cookie to the CookieManager:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);

cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
cookieManager.setCookie(ApiConstants.BASIC_ROOT_URL, cookieString);
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
```

But, none of this tried have gone, someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is an oldish question but I figured I'd publish it if only for myself.

This is not as hard as it seems, but without documentation, you have to look in the test cases to figure it out. I've taken the code I've used and wrapped it in a helper class. There is definitely more you could do with it (setting expiry and what not), but this should be enough to satisfy the poster's requirements:

```
package com.example;


import android.content.Context;

import com.koushikdutta.async.http.Headers;
import com.koushikdutta.ion.Ion;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/*
This is adapted from my own code... so I'm not sure this will work exactly like this but it'll give you a starting point
*/
public class IonCookieManager {
    CookieManager manager;

    public IonCookieManager(Context context) {
        Ion ion = Ion.getDefault(context);
        manager = ion.getCookieMiddleware().getCookieManager();
    }

    public void storeCookies(URLConnection conn) throws IOException {

        List<String> cookies = conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
        URI uri = URI.create(conn.getURL().toString());
        if(cookies != null) {
            storeCookies(uri, cookies);
        }
    }

    public void storeCookies(URI uri, List<String> cookies) throws IOException {
        Headers headers = new Headers();
        headers.addAll("Set-Cookie", cookies);

        manager.put(uri, headers.getMultiMap());
    }

    public void storeCookie(URI uri, String cookieName, String cookieValue) throws IOException {
        List<String> cookie = new ArrayList<String>();
        cookie.add(String.format("%s=%s", cookieName, cookieValue));
        storeCookies(uri, cookie);
    }

}
```

[Also as a gist](https://gist.github.com/littlefyr/e5bd337b53b1e42328b0).

Comment: thanky very much sir, can you explain about how to use this tip?